# Show that $f_1,f_2 \not\models f_3$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $f_1=(\forall x(r(x) \vee \neg p(x))$, $f_2=(\exists x(r(x)\rightarrow q(x)))$ and $f_3 = (\forall x(\neg p(x)\rightarrow q(x)))$. Show that $f_1,f_2 \not\models f_3$.

My attempt: lets assume that $\mathcal{A}=(\{a\},S)$ such that $r^{\mathcal{A}}=p^{\mathcal{A}}=q^{\mathcal{A}} = \{a\}$. Then obviously $\mathcal{A} \models f_1$ and $\mathcal{A} \models f_2$. Im not certain how i should continue. Any help is appreciated. Should i consider cases?

For example $I[a / x] \models r(x)$ and $I[a / x] \models p(x)$ then $I[a / x] \not\models \neg p(x)$ so $f_1,f_2 \not\models f_3$ in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're asking is to show that $f_1$ and $f_2$ being valid does not imply that $f_3$ is valid. I'm assuming $r$,$p$, and $q$ are all unary predicates.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but all you have to show is that there exists some model with an element $a$ such that $r(a) \vee \neg p(a)$ and $r(a) \to q(a)$ are valid, but $\neg p(a) \to q(a)$ is not valid. Before you read on, I recommend seeing if you can find this counterexample for yourself, however I have included my reasoning under this spoiler for you.

> Breaking what we have down further we have that $r(a)$ and $q(a)$ are false and $p(a)$ is true. This gives you a counterexample model. The domain of our model is $D = \{a\}$, and our interpretation function is defined with $I(r) = \emptyset$, $I(q) =\emptyset$, and $I(p) = \{a\}$

Therefore, since this is not true in every model, we have that $f_3$ does not follow from those premises.

Comment: Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a structure such that $\neg p(x)$ is true, but $r(x)$ and $q(x)$ arent.Such structure is for example $p^{\mathcal{A}} = \{a\}$ and $r^{\mathcal{A}}=q^{\mathcal{A}} = \emptyset$. Therefore $I[a / x] \models \neg p(x)$, but $I[a / x] \not\models q(x)$. Which proves the claim.

Comment: Your first sentence isn't quite correct (though this is a bit pedantic), as those predicates contain variables, not elements from the domain. You want $\neg p(x)$ and such to take those truth values under a variable assignment. I'm not necessarily familiar with your notation, but I can intuit what you mean, and this looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Work backwards. You want a model which makes $f_3$ false, while making $f_1$ and $f_2$ true.

All it takes to make $f_3$ false is (i) for there to be  *something* in the domain which satisfies neither $p(x)$ nor $q(x)$. Hold on to that thought!

Suppose in fact (ii) *nothing* satisfies $p$, then $f_1$ will be true.

Suppose (iii) *nothing* satisfies $r$, then $f_2$ will be true (since for any $x$, the conditional $(r(x) \to q(x))$ has a false antecedent and will be true).

It is easy to make (i), (ii) and (iii) true together!